# Read a textfile to search for a multiple strings and delete the rest of the line

Tags: c#, text-files

UPDATE: 
I have created some code which reads a C++ file and outputs it into a .txt file. I want to process the text file to remove certain words etc.

In the example below I have removed the comments from the code (i.e. a line containing //). How would I look for muliple strings at the one time?

Say for example I want to find "public :" and delete it also.

Thanks for any help & appologies about my previous question.

Code for my class:

```
class ProcessFiles
{
    string output = "path to .txt file"
    string filename = "path to .h C++ file"

    public void Remove_Comments()
    { 
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (!line.Contains("//".ToString()))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for my Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    C__to_C.ProccessFiles process_files;

    public Form1()
    {
        Initialize Component();
        process_files = new C__to_C.ProccessFiles();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventsArgs e)
    {
        process_files.Remove_Comments();
    }
```

Comment: Where, in the code, are you looking/checking for _that_ certain text?

Comment: Do you have `System.String.AddLine()` method? Fancy! Few things here: Use `using` to properly dispose a stream then check `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` and `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines()` functions.

Comment: @mshsayem I have updated the code which I am using, please see above.

Comment: @Emily you got `File.ReadAllLines()` right, you just need an extra step for `File.WriteAllLines()`. It's a one line: `File.WriteAllLines("output path"), File.ReadAllLines("input path").Where(x => !x.Contains("//")));` Obviously change the condition to something that matches your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProcessFiles
{
    string output = "path to .txt file"
    string filename = "path to .h C++ file"

    public void Remove_Comments()
    { 
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (!line.Contains("//".ToString()))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line.Replace("public :", ""));
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will be useful